# Slack API button: How to present all texts in one button?

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-block-kit

I'm using slack bot to send messages to users. There are some buttons in the message which looks like:
[image]

One issue is that when the text body on the button is too long, it will be hidden. Is there anyway that I can make all text present on the button?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest keeping the information as plain text(mrkdwn),

 and add button next to it with label such as 'more info..'

Comment: yeah, maybe I can present my content in this way, thanks:)